# Git rebase conflicts when directory tree changed

Tags: git, rebase, directory-structure

I have a branch in a fork of a repo. The upstream repo structure has been changed slightly by renaming one of the top-level directories. My branch creates a new subdirectory with files in the affected directory. When I try to rebase, I am getting many `CONFLICT (file location)` issues. I have come across this before but usually gits suggestion has been correct and I've been able to just `git add .` and `git rebase --continue`. However, in this case the suggestion git provides is totally incorrect. To clarify:

`SomeName/SubfolderName/` has become `SomeOtherName/SubfolderName/` in the upstream repo.

The files I added in my fork are in `SomeName/SubfolderName/ANewSubfolder/`. When I rebase, git tells me;
`CONFLICT (file location): SomeName/SubfolderName/ANewSubfolder/Filename.ext added in a1c2e3... SomeCommitName inside a directory that was renamed in HEAD, suggesting it should perhaps be moved to ANewSubfolder/Filename.ext`

As you can see, the suggestion is totally incorrect (presumably because the files I added in that commit are new, and git doesn't have anything to compare against to determine where they should go)

How do I tell git that `SomeOtherName/SubfolderName/` is the correct location for `ANewSubfolder/Filename.ext`?

Comment: With `git mv`. Perhaps run first `git add` in the location where git placed it currently, then `git mv` to the right location

Answer (score 0):

When Git makes this "suggestion", as far as I know, Git takes no *action* on it.  There may be plans to make it take action in the future, although if this comes to pass, I would hope that the message itself ("suggesting that it should perhaps") would change as well.

In any case, here is what you need to know:

1. `git rebase` is—mostly—a series of automated `git cherry-pick` operations.
2. Each `git cherry-pick` is a kind of merge, much like `git merge` (but made weird to make it do a cherry-pick instead of a merge).
3. When there is a merge conflict and Git stops in the middle like this, **you are in full control of the result**.  It is your responsibility to *construct* the correct final commit.

In this case, the answer is: make sure the file *is* in the right location in your working tree, and then run `git add` on that file.  If necessary—I don't think it will be—run `git rm` or `git rm --cached` on the *wrong* path.

Meanwhile, it's worth covering each of the above three points in more detail.  If you are already deeply familiar with rebase, feel free to go straight to [What are the files in the Staging Area after a merge conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68754054/1256452)

#### Rebase is repeated cherry-picking, plus a bit

Rebasing is the process of copying commits to new-and-improved versions.  This means that the `git rebase` command, at the most basic level, needs three inputs:

- The current branch name, whatever that is.
- A list of commits to copy.  Copying is necessary because *no part of any existing commit can ever be changed*.  That includes both the source snapshot *and* the parent commit hash ID.  When we use rebase, we are doing so in order to "change" the snapshots and/or the parent hash IDs.  We literally can't do this; instead, we make new-and-improved commits, that have *different* hash IDs, and in turn link back to each other (and then the new base).
- The place where the copies are to go.

We might start by making some set of commits:

```
          I--J--K   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- master
```

(Newer commits appear to the right; a branch name *finds* the last commit that we say is "on the branch"; and each commit links *backwards* to its parent.)

Meanwhile, *someone else* makes some new commit `L` and (in some way or another) gets it on our `master`:

```
          I--J--K   <-- feature (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H--L   <-- master
```

We now have to take our `I-J-K` commits, which *were* good, and make new and improved versions that take commit `L` into account and will look like this:

```
          I--J--K   [abandoned]
         /
...--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I'-J'-K'  <-- feature (HEAD)
```

The set-of-commits to copy, then, is simply `I`, `J`, and `K`.  These letters stand in for actual Git hash IDs, which are big and ugly and random-looking; the only way to find them out is to run `git log` or similar.

The place to *put the copies* is "after commit `L`".  That way, they come after the updated `master`.

Once the three commits are copied, the *branch name* must move—rather sharply.  Branch names are how we, and Git, *find* the (last) commits, and normally we move them one step at a time by *adding one new commit*.  The new commit automatically points back to what *was* the last commit; now the new commit *is* the last commit.

Here, though, we're going to check out commit `L` as a sort of temporary branch, add *three* new commits, and then yank the name `feature` over so that it points to `K'` instead of to `K`.  This abandons the original three commits (so it's important that nobody else *have* those commits, lest they be using them for something and want to keep them).

- It's easy for Git to find the current branch name (Git has to do this all the time, so internally it's pretty trivial).
- To find the commits to copy, we run `git rebase` with an argument that tells Git what *not* to copy instead.  That is, we run `git rebase master`, for instance.  That tells Git *not* to copy commits `L`, `H`, `G`, or anything earlier.

  Git was never going to copy `L` in the first place, because the set of commits **to** copy ends with `K`.  But the initial to-copy copy goes—in reverse order—`K`, then `J`, then `I`, then `H`, then `G`, then everything earlier too: everything `git log` would show.  From this list, we have to *subtract away* commits that *shouldn't* be copied, and that list includes the set of commits we find by starting at `master` and working backwards.

  (This "start at a branch name and work backwards" theme occurs over and over in Git.)
- To find where to put the copies, Git uses the argument `master` that we gave it on the command line.

Hence the single argument `master`, in `git rebase master`, provides both *what not to copy* and *where to put the copies*.  Sometimes this single argument is not sufficient; for that, we have `git rebase --onto`.  We can skip over the details here, leaving that for later.

#### Cherry-pick is a merge

Let's look at how `git cherry-pick` actually has to work.  Imagine we've started our rebase:

```
git rebase master
```

and have gotten this far:

```
          I--J--K   <-- feature
         /
...--G--H--L   <-- master
            \
             I'  <-- HEAD
```

Here we are, on this temporary branch, having "copied" commit `I` via cherry-pick.  How, precisely, *did* Git copy commit `I`?  Let's think about what a commit is:

- It's a (read-only) snapshot (of every source file) ...
- ... with metadata including things like some names and email addresses, and a log message, and—crucially for Git's internal workings—a *parent commit hash ID*.

Commit `I` therefore has all the files, but so does its parent commit, commit `H`.  Git can thus run:

```
git diff <hash-of-H> <hash-of-I>
```

to see what files *changed*, between `H` and `I`.

To "copy" those changes to make `I'`, Git should now check out commit `L` and apply the same changes.  If we changed the `README` file and one other file `f1.c`, and *they* changed only the `Documentation/background.txt` file, our changes slip in easily: there can be no conflicts here.

But ... what if *they* changed the `README` file too?  What if they *added some lines at the top,* where our changes is near the bottom?  Git needs to know to change the *moved* lines, to account for the stuff they added at the top.

This—combining *their* changes with *our* changes—is precisely what a merge does.  Git needs to compare the snapshot in `H` to that in `I` to see what *we* did, but also needs to compare the snapshot in `H` to that in `L` to see what *they* did.

Given these two comparisons, Git can now *merge* our changes with their changes.  If the merged changes don't conflict, Git can apply *both* sets of changes to the `README` from the merge base `H`, giving us the new `README` for new commit `I'`.  Git should then go on to make a new commit, but this new commit isn't a *merge commit*, it's just an ordinary commit.  Moreover, the parent of this ordinary commit is commit `L`.  So that gets us commit `I'`, and gets us to this point.

To copy commit `J`, Git does the same kind of thing.  This time, though, the "merge" compares the snapshot in `I` vs that in `J` to see what *we* changed, and the snapshot in `I` vs that in `I'` to see what "they" changed.

Think about that for a while.  It might be obvious that this works, and it might not.  (In fact, it *does* work, quite well most of the time.)

That's the underlying mechanism of a cherry-pick: Git performs a standard three-way merge, with the "merge base" being the *parent of the commit to copy*, the *current commit* being the one we have checked out right now and found by `HEAD`, and the "other" commit—the one that `git merge` calls `theirs`—being *our commit that is being copied*.

This means that during a cherry-pick, including that invoked by rebase, the `--theirs` option means *our commit*.  The `--ours` option means ... well, it's messy: it was commit `L` for the first cherry-pick, and now it's commit `I'`, a commit we built by copying `I`.  So `--theirs` is ours, and `--ours` is ... a mix: theirs *plus* ours.

This, though, is *why* cherry-picking is merging.  There are three commits as the three inputs; Git uses the usual three-way merge algorithm to combine the two sets of changes.  It's just the *commit itself* that's not a merge, in the end.

If we have merge conflicts, we're responsible for resolving them.

#### Resolving merge conflicts

The last thing to know—although it's something you should really learn when learning how `git merge` works, which you should do *before* learning about rebase—is that `git merge` works using Git's *index* aka *staging area*.  Rather than write this again, though, I'm just going to link to [What are the files in the Staging Area after a merge conflict?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68754054/1256452)  Your job, in resolving the merge conflict, is to deal with the nonzero stage numbered files that *are* in the index, and replace them with stage-zero files.  While you're doing that, you can make *any changes you like* to Git's index.  Whatever is in the index / staging-area, in the end, when you run `git rebase --continue`, is what goes into the final commit (which is then the `--ours` commit in the *next* cherry-pick).